# Why does strafe-jumping/bunny-hopping work?

Tags: counter-strike, counter-strike-source, quake-3

Long story short, I want to know the math behind Strafe Jumping (and any other odd ways of acceleration), and I'm not sure if such info exists. If it does, could somebody either write the formula down or at least link me to any relevant information?

Comment: Quake 3 was GPL'ed and you can go digging in the source if you so choose: https://github.com/id-Software/Quake-III-Arena  Other than that, you might have a better chance of getting this answered on a forum for a [game based on the source,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Id_Tech_3#Projects_based_on_the_GPL_source_release) or perhaps at our sister site, [gamedev](http://gamedev.stachexchange.com)

Comment: The calculations for movement within Quake 3 are explained very well in this [strafe jumping theory article on F3Quake](http://www.funender.com/quake/articles/strafing_theory.html) but as mentioned by agent86 for further information you're probably going to want to communicate with a more specialist source.

Comment: I hope you don't mind, but I've added the `counter-strike` and `counter-strike-source` tags, since this technique is commonly done in both of those games as well, and works exactly the same way.  This should open the question to a broader audience.

Comment: Thank you for editing the question. I wasnt really sure how to write it myself, since its 0:48 AM and my brain doesnt work too well that time o' day c:

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/807/what-is-bunny-hopping

Comment: @Alok Not an exact duplicate. The question you linked is only asking for a definition, whereas here we want to know *why* it works. As nice as it would be to have all of the information in one question I think this one is legitimately different and deserves a separate answer here.

Comment: @SadlyNot: Check the answers, for e.g. http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/2896/25150 - they go into great detail on the *why* part as well.

Comment: @SadlyNot originally this question was just asking for a definition and the math behind it, it was edited by another user to make it a 'why'.

Comment: When you search for why does it work you do get the original first. Is there still a point to closing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Reading through [the link](http://www.funender.com/quake/articles/strafing_theory.html) provided by @pixel above, it appears the reason that strafe-jumping works is actually pretty simple.

Instead of capping the maximum velocity, the authors of Quake/CS cap the net-acceleration of the player such that the velocity in the acceleration's direction will not exceed the max velocity.  This means that, if you accelerate in a direction other than the direction you want to move in, it is possible to exceed the maximum velocity.

I'm not sure why they didn't simply cap the maximum velocity itself, but since that is the obvious solution and almost certainly the one they tried first, they must have had a good reason to change it.

Comment: It's kinda confusing to use 'max velocity' when what you're saying implies that there is no max velocity, except for the direction that you 'want to move in'. What do you mean by 'want to move in' - the direction you are facing? The direction your are moving with WADS?

Comment: @SadlyNot: No, max velocity is exactly what I mean.  They cap the acceleration on a frame-by-frame basis in an attempt to cap the velocity, but that does not work as they likely expected.  By "direction you want to move in," I mean the direction you *will* be moving in, after the acceleration-vector is added to the velocity.  This is separate from both the direction you're facing and the direction you're accelerating *(aka "direction you're moving with WASD")*

Comment: Ok. My english has it's limits. What is "Net-acceleration"?

Comment: @ChaosPointDK: "net" means "total."  It means the combined acceleration caused by all forces (holding "forward," holding "right," gravity, friction)

Comment: Aaaaaaaah... well since its summer, my brain doesnt seem to be working at even 80%, but even then, I still think I understand dis. Acceptin question c:

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Ah so that's why bunny hoping relies on low degree angles. You answer confused me because usually a cap implies a constant, which is not the case here. My bad. I guess the word 'reduces' would make more sense to me but your answer is fine as-is.

Comment: Use the Camping Gaz HUD for the DeFRaG mod for Q3. It shows you how it works by showing what direction you should face to accelerate.

Comment: Great answer! Re: "I'm not sure why they didn't simply cap the maximum velocity itself" -- The usual reason to avoid this is that you want *other* forces to be able to accelerate you above the max running speed, whether it's for rocket jumping, jump pads, or other external forces.